# GLS estimation procedure for the Random Effect model

Tags: econometrics, paneldata, data, fixed-effects, first-difference

Consider a simple panel regression model: $$y_{it}=\beta x_{it}+a_i+u_{it}=\beta x_{it}+\epsilon_{it}$$ where $\epsilon_{it}=a_i+u_{it}$

Question: I need to explain the fixed effects estimator and the first-differenced estimator for the Fixed Effects model. Describe how the GLS estimation procedure works for the Random Effect model.

Comment: Welcome. Your question is a bit too broad. You can begin with the [Baltagi textbook](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-53953-5), the [Wooldridge textbook](https://www.amazon.com/Econometric-Analysis-Cross-Section-Panel/dp/0262232588), or perhaps even the [Stata manual for -xtreg-](https://www.stata.com/manuals/xtxtreg.pdf).